# Maven 2, Nexus and snapshot timestamps are causing problems with eclipse:eclipse

Tags: maven-2, jenkins, m2eclipse

We have moved from Archiva to Nexus and are still using Maven 2.

We execute eclipse:eclipse locally so that Eclipse .project and .classpath files are generated, based on the dependencies in the POMs, and then we import the projects into Eclipse to do our development.  We don't use M2Eclipse for a variety of reasons.

Since using Nexus, we have the problem that projects don't always reference each other in the workspace, rather they reference the respective JAR.

I have noticed that Nexus is appending a timestamp to the JAR name, and the MVN output states, e.g.:

```
[INFO] Artifact myapp-bom:jar:7.3.0.2.1-SNAPSHOT already available as a workspace project, but with different version. Expected: 7.3.0.2.1-20120508.115037-68, found: 7.3.0.2.1-SNAPSHOT
```

I get the feeling that is the reason why eclipse:eclipse generates .classpath files which contains *JAR references* (based on local maven repo) rather than *project references*.  When we used Archiva (and there were no timestamps) then we used to get *project references*, and that is exactly what we want.

Has anyone else had this problem and how is it solved?  I read that maven 3 forces timestamps to always be generated.  Again, how do you get eclipse:eclipse to generate sensible .classpath files?

Cheers,
Ant

PS - some of our projects come from different SVN repositories.  It seems that if the Eclipse Projects are refernced in the parent pom, eclipse:eclipse creates a project reference, but if the Eclipse Projects are from a different parent pom, but still in the workspace, then it can only generate JAR references.

Comment: Which Eclipse version are you using?

Comment: 3.6 or some of us are using IBM RAD (also a 3.6 variant).

Comment: I don't think Eclipse Versions are relevant, because the .classpath file which eclipse:eclipse generates is like this:    

<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/ch/mycompany/myapp-bom/7.3.0.2.1-SNAPSHOT/myapp-bom-7.3.0.2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/ch/mycompany/myapp-bom/7.3.0.2.1-SNAPSHOT/myapp-bom-7.3.0.2.1-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar"/>

I.e. its a JAR reference and not a Project reference.

Comment: Which version of IBM RAD? RAD causes always headaches.

Comment: Forget RAD - the problem occurs with "Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Helios Release
Build id: 20100617-1415" which is a 3.6 version.

Comment: Why don't you use m2eclipse with Helios release or use newer Indigo with m2e support. Do you have particular need to use this old release and use the mvn eclipse:eclipse plugin?

Comment: Longer term, yes we will use m2eclipse.  But not today.  And this problem is causing problems today.  Archiva didn't cause the problem, and Nexus does.  Is there a way to force Nexus to not generate the timestamps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by using maven-eclipse-plugin (eclipse:eclipse) version 2.9, rather than 2.8!  Doh...